# How to change cover slide font size without affecting slide footer font size

Tags: beamer, header-footer, fontsize, presentations, covers

I'm using the template from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uib-beamer-theme/ddsnzprthmfv. I noticed that the default font size for the title, subtitle and author's affiliations on the cover slide is sort of big, so I tried to reduce the font as follows:

```
\author{\large{Martin Helsø}}
\title{\large{Beamer example}}
\subtitle{\large{Usage of the theme \texttt{UiB}}}
```

which seems to be successful:

[image]

However, the font size of the footer seems to have been blown up and over-written:

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the font settings with the `\setbeamerfont{...}{family = ..., size = ..., series = ...}` command in the preamble of the document:

```
\setbeamerfont{author}{size = \large, series = \bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size = \large, series = \bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{family = \rmfamily, size = \large}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) Just to add, it works only when the above lines are placed after `\usetheme{UiB}`.